# ggplot - y axe limits when labels=labels

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, percentage

I have a plot where the y axis is transformed in percents; I would like to put limits on it to show only the high percents (from 50% to 100%) but it does not work :

```
  ggplot(myData,aes(x=A_factor, y=some_numeric_data, fill=factor(Another_factor))) + 
  geom_bar(position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE),stat = "identity", color="white") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent, limits=c(50,100))
```

I also tried with labels = percent_format.

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values underlying the labels are decimal representations. Your limits should be set between 0 and 1. In your case:

```
limits = c(0.5, 1)
```

Comment: I cant' believe I did not figured that out. I face another problem now : it gives me the limits I wanted, but now the plot is empty...

Comment: Are your data in percents? Also, please consider accepting the answer (check mark to the left) if this answer helped you

Comment: No, the data are not in percent.

Comment: Try `range(myData$some_number)` check to see if it's actually a percentage. Debugging your data and approach is something you should do when something "doesn't work"

Comment: It's not, it goes from 0 to 2216. The labels = scales::percent automatically convert the data in percent (it works when I don't try to limit the y axis).

Comment: You might want to check out `?scales::percent`. The way you are using it is just to construct a label. It does absolutely nothing to the underlying data.  What you are plotting is the values of 0 to 2216, which is not a percentage representation of your data but it happens to have labels between "0%" and "221600%".